# Creating a OpenID Provider in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

I have an existing website that I want to turn into an OpenID provider. All my user accounts are stored in a mysql table.

I figured since an OpenID is represented as a URL, I am going to do something like: http://login.mydomain.com/username

I've setup a subdomain, and created an htaccess that redirects all URLs to /login.php?username=[username]

The way I see it, and tell me if I'm wrong, someone goes to let's say StackOverflow, they enter http://login.mydomain.com/myUsername. They get to a page on my server that asks for their password (since I already know their username), I check that it matches, and return the key?

People online recommended using Zend_OpenId_Provider. I've been reading their documentation (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.provider.html), but I find it very confusing. They have no real world example where the user login/password are stored in a database.

I've also seen php-open-id (http://github.com/openid/php-openid), but no help there either.

It seems to be a pretty common thing to do. Is there a tutorial out there or an example I can easily adapt?

Comment: I'd like to get some examples of this too. I'm heading towards becoming OpenID Provider too, we could collaborate. Although I plan to use Janrain OpenID Enabled: http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled, since Zend has failed some of my requirements. And I'm afraid you got to read the source...

Comment: I'm open to openid-enabled or any other. It's just so hard to find help out there to become a provider. I've set a small bounty on the question. Maybe it will help ... Vote for this question.

Comment: The quality of Zends official documentation is poor. They hardly provide real world examples.

Comment: Hi, I have a PHP project that aims to provide such features. See https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/oauth2-server-library and let's discuss if you are interested

Answer (score 8):

As you tagged this question with zend-framework I think you want to implement this with ZF.

Look at the constructor of the `Zend_OpenId_Provider`

```
public function __construct($loginUrl = null,
                            $trustUrl = null,
                            Zend_OpenId_Provider_User $user = null,
                            Zend_OpenId_Provider_Storage $storage = null,
                            $sessionTtl = 3600)
```

The important one is the `$storage` parameter.

In the example on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.provider.html they do not pass any parameters. That means by default the `Zend_OpenId_Provider_Storage_File` provider is used. Again this one would store per default in files in your TEMP directory (`/tmp` on Linux).

Basically the example should be fully functional. You could register some more users by calling `$server->register($someid, $somepassword);`

But as it stores accounts per default in the temporary directory, you should replace that line by something like this (if it is okay to store accounts in files):

```
$dir = "/var/lib/myopenidusers";
mkdir($dir);
$server = new Zend_OpenId_Provider(null, null, null, new Zend_OpenId_Provider_Storage($dir) );
```

Now, if you prefer to **store your users in a database** you have to implement your own Provider_Storage.

Have a look at the abstract class `abstract class Zend_OpenId_Provider_Storage`. This are the methods you have to implement.

Comment: Note that I already have all my users in my database. Do I still need to "register" them?

Comment: It seems I have to write all of it. I just want the "login" part of it to be done through my mysql table. Here I need to implement all the code from scratch, most of which I don't even understand ...

Answer (score 2):

I tried everything listed here, Community ID, simpleid, janrain, etc, along with all those that claim to be providers from [OpenID Wiki / Libraries](http://wiki.openid.net/w/page/12995176/Libraries) and failed. I then stumbled across [Prairie](http://www.barnraiser.org/prairie/) and got it running in about an hour. A little more work of changing the queries in index.php and login.php and I was getting it to work against my user table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [phpMyId](http://siege.org/phpmyid.php). See the demo from http://phpmyid.com/. Every details about [phpMyId](http://siege.org/phpmyid.php) can be found at http://siege.org/phpmyid.php.

Comment: phpMyId is great but single-user only out-of-the-box, and I'm not sure it does OpenID 2 (?). You might do better starting with http://simpleid.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can try JanRain Engage (http://www.janrain.com/products/engage). It is a simplified interface for OpenID integration with web applications. The free version should be good enough for all practical purposes.

Comment: Engage is to ACCEPT OpenId, not to be a provider. You might be thinking of FEDERATE, which isn't free.

Answer (score 0):

We use: http://source.keyboard-monkeys.org/projects/show/communityid

From their website:

"Community-ID is an OpenID  implementation in PHP which is OpenID 2.0 compliant. Community-ID is build to 100% on Open Source software and is release under the BSD license. Users can keep track of their trusted sites and manage them. The login to C-ID can be username/passowrd or a One Time Password with Yubikey. A user can have multiple profiles like with privat or business contact information.

For Community-ID administrators statistics are available to track registration of new users, authorized users per day or the number of trusted sites. Administrators can set the site in maintenance mode or send emails to all registered users.

For user data and authentication, admin can choose the default db storage, or to connect to an LDAP server. Current confirmed supported is OpenLDAP. Other LDAP servers should work also fine."

Comment: I am trying to set this up, I run a small business with me and 3 others, we run 4 websites, and would like SSO, I have set up the SSO part, but not sure how to then forward the other sites to login with this :/

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleID](http://simpleid.sf.net/) is a small and nice to use + setup OpenID provider software. I use it myself and can't complain.